# Symbolic variable for If argument

Tags: conditional, expression-test

i want to realize an if in this way :

```
var=expression;

If[var==0,
Print[Hello]];

If[var!=0,
Print[Hey]];
```

The system doesn't know if `expression` is equal to zero. But i know that it is different from zero because it is symbolic. Is there a way to pass the first if with a symbolic variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SameQ` and `UnsameQ` instead of `Equal` and `Unequal`:

```
If[var === 0, Print[Hello]];
If[var =!= 0, Print[Hey]];
```

> Hey